# How do i show image animation on iphone

Tags: iphone, image

I have a  animated gif ( like [this](http://www.indiavilas.com/kidscorner/telugu/a.gif) one ) , when I show in an image view on my iphone app it just shows the first frame . This behavior is consistent with the apple documentation . 
I was wondering what is the best way to achieve this on the iphone ?

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/899472/how-do-i-show-image-animation-on-iphone

Comment: @ChrisF: This is the original.  The duplicate is now closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's some code that I've got in a current project. I've got a loop to put images standy2 through to standby7.png into an array. Am using imageWithContentsOfFile since that seems to be a little better on memory usage.

```
standbyAnimationImages = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (NSUInteger i=2; i<=7; i++) {
    filename = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"standby%d", i];
    [standbyAnimationImages addObject:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:filename ofType:@"png"]]];
}

imageViewAnimation.animationImages = standbyAnimationImages;
imageViewAnimation.animationDuration = 2;
imageViewAnimation.animationRepeatCount = 0;
[imageViewAnimation startAnimating];
```

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 1):

Split it up into separate PNG or JPG images then load each frame into a `UIImageView` and use its animation methods. Take a look at the `UIImageView` documentation under "Animating Images." It's pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

If you export all of the frames to individual images you can make a `UIImage` view, set the `animationImages` property to an `NSArray` containing all of your frames as `UIImages`. Then call `[imageView startAnimating]`.

Kyle