# Image editing in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, image-manipulation

I want to create image as like cartoon of any particular image in iphone using some image processing . Can any one know how to change image in cartoon . or any algo to edit images in cartoon.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The question is unclear, if you are trying to create sort of an animated gif in the iPhone, there are examples of this on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/899461/how-do-i-show-image-animation-on-iphone

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5864752/iphone-image-editing

Answer (score 4):

https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage
this framework is very helpful